# using ng-module giving cross domain error

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple html and on that page i am trying to include some other html page for user detail. but some how the page is not being included.

On index page i have following code

```
<form>
            <input type="Search" placeHolder="Enter Name" ng-model="user"/><br>
            <input type="Button" value="Search" ng-click="Search()"/>

            <div ng-include src="'userDetail.html'">
            </div>
        </form>
```

I have tried following.

```
  <ng-include src="'userDetail.html'"></ng-include>
  <div ng-include="'userDetail.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include src="'userDetail.html'"></div>
```

The error code I am getting is

```
 Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Please see attached screenshot for further details.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is right in its description. You need to run your app in any of the listed protocols (for local development that's http or https 99,9% of the time). Instead you are running it as a file on the disk (notice the `file://` in your URL).

You must use a local HTTP server (like Apache or IIS) or use a IDE with build-in server (I recommend [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) for its great preview function) to serve your content to be able to properly test the application locally.